# Custom socket connection with Weblogic, JNDI and SSL

Tags: java, ssl, ejb, weblogic, jndi

Does anyone know if it is possible to perform a JNDI lookup on Weblogic using a custom SSL socket connection other than the built-in connection method?

```
Hashtable<String, String> ht = new Hashtable<String, String>();
    ht.put(Context.SECURITY_PROTOCOL, "ssl");
    ht.put(Context.SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION, "simple");
    ht.put("weblogic.socket", "mypackage.MyCustomSSLSocket"); //SOMETHING LIKE THIS
InitialContext context = new InitialContext(ht);
```

MyCustomSSLSocket will be configured with my trust store...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't found the way, I think in this case it is impossible, there is description how to configure 
[T3 client with custom SSLSocketFactory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52369236/t3-client-with-custom-sslsocketfactory/53738095#53738095)