# T3 client with custom SSLSocketFactory

Tags: java, tomcat, ssl, ejb, weblogic

I have my T3 client code like this:

```
private InitialContext initContext() {
    Properties p = new Properties();
    p.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "weblogic.jndi.WLInitialContextFactory");
    p.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, context.providerURL);

    for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : getEnvironmentProperties().entrySet()) {
        p.put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
    }

    InitialContext res = null;
    try {
        res = new InitialContext(p);
    } catch (NamingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return res;
}
```

My t3 client deployed on Tomcat (uses wlthint3client-12.1.3.jar) and trying to lookup remote bean of external system which deployed on Weblogic.

However when I trying to perform new InitialContext(p) I receive SSLHandshake exception, because it gets standart SSLSocketFactory with standart SSLConext and standart java trust store.

My question - is there any way to give to InitialContext some property which will override SSLSocketFacory. My aim is to populate my cutom trust store to this t3 client.

Changing standart trust store like this

```
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", "pathToTrustStore");
```

works fine, however in case if my t3 client is used to communicate with 2 different external systems, it might be a problem in doing so.

Is there some property that I can populate?

```
Properties p = new Properties();
p.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "weblogic.jndi.WLInitialContextFactory");
**p.put("CUSTOM SSL SOCKET FACTORY, "MY CLASS");**
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was solved by adding few parameters on application side

```
export JAVA_OPTS ="$JAVA_OPTS -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=path/truststore.jks"
export JAVA_OPTS ="$JAVA_OPTS -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=changeIT"
```